# Shared Azure FSlogix Environments and Issues with Shared Volumes

Tags: windows, azure, shared-folders, sharepoint, cloud

We have 20 users split over two separate Azure/Windows 10 desktop environments. FSlogix is doing AD duties, and we have a shared SharePoint volume that everyone accesses via their remote desktop. The setup was working well until recently, when it was decided to clean up and reorganize folders and files. It has since become obvious that moving a single folder can cause duplicate folders. Moving deep folder structures is all-but impossible. We have something on the order of ~300,000 files. I've been told that this is too much for a single shared volume to handle regarding syncing.

What are some ways to address this issue? Is there a better way/environment that will give us what we need to be productive?